# Angular 6 - Pass complex JSON Object in an HTTP Get request

Tags: angular, get, parameter-passing

How can I do a HTTP get request and pass an JSON Object.

When I used [Angular Datatable - Server side the Angular way](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way), they are using a `post` request:

```
this.http.post<DataTablesResponse>(
   'https://angular-datatables-demo-server.herokuapp.com/',
   dataTablesParameters, {}
)
```

For some reason, i would like to use **get** request. So how to do that in a `get` request?

The `dataTablesParameters` is a JSON Object, something like:

```
{
    "order": [{
        "column": 0,
        "dir": "asc"
    }],
    "start": 0,
    "length": 10,
    "search": {
        "value": "",
        "regex": false
    }
    ...
}
```

here is what i tried:

```
this.http.get<DataTablesResponse>(
      '/dashboard/roles/?format=datatables', 
      {params: dataTablesParameters}
    )
```

**but i am unable to access values of `search` parameter?**

Comment: You cannot pass a body in GET requests, the HTTP protocol does not allow it. You would have to pass it in the URL somehow, but at that point it seems easier to use another HTTP method

Comment: @user184994 do you mean i need to use HTTP POST?

Comment: Yes, or PUT, just not GET

Comment: @simple_human, did you find a better way for it?

Comment: @raga I used `post` instead of `get`